# How to auto overflow-y on flexbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox, overflow

I am making a custom control using Jquery. It takes a list of items from data-list attribute, and output an opposing listbox. I want to have relative control of the height by controlling how many listitems are shown, and have the remainder scrollable. The height is working, but I cannot get scrollbar to appear by setting overflow-y: auto.

[image]

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/c4p/pen/YYJbaq)

```
$.fn.olbox = function(options) {

 this.css("display","flex"); 
 this.css("align-items","flex-start"); // required to limit width of enclosed box

var itemslist = this.attr("data-list").split(",");
var header = "<div class='olb-header' style='padding: 0 3px 3px 5px; font-size: 125%; font-weight: 900;'>HEADER</div>";
  var footer = "<div class='olb-footer' style='text-align: center; padding: 5px 3px 3px 0; font-size: 50%; text-decoration: italics;'>FOOTER</div>";
var titlesbox = "<div class='titles' style='display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: center;'>" + "<div class='yes-title' style='border-bottom: 1px solid black; padding: 0 5px;'>YES</div><div class='items-title' style='font-weight: 900; border-bottom: 1px solid black; ; padding: 0 5px;'>ITEMS</div><div class='no-title' style='border-bottom: 1px solid black'>NO</div>" + "</div>";
var yes = "<div class='yes-col'><div class='yes-checks'>";
  var items = "<div class='items-col'><div class='items2'>";
  var no = "<div class='no-col'><div class='no-checks'>";
  for (i = 0; i < itemslist.length; ++i) {
    yes = yes + "<div><input class='yes' type='checkbox' data-text='" + itemslist[i] + "' value=true style='margin: 0'></div>";
    items = items + "<div id='items-text'>" + itemslist[i] + "</div>"
  no = no + "<div><input class='no' type='checkbox' data-text='" + itemslist[i] + "' value=false style='margin:0;'></div>";
  }
  yes += "</div></div>";
  no += "</div></div>";
  items += "</div></div>";

  var cont =  "<div class='olb-container' style='display: flex; flex-direction: column; text-align:center; height: 100%; padding: 0 3px 0 3px;'>" + header + titlesbox + "<div class='itemsbox' style='display: flex; justify-content: space-around; margin: 2.5px 0 2.5px 0;'>" + yes + items + no +  "</div>" + footer ;
  this.append(cont);

// limit lines to 3  
  $('.itemsbox').css("line-height","1em");
  $('.itemsbox').css("height","3em");
  $('.itemsbox').css("overflow-y","auto"); // why not scrollbar? remove it and overflow seen

  // Apply Defaults/Options
  $('.olb-container').css({
    'border' : '2px solid black',
    'border-radius': '5px'
  })

  return this.css({
  });
};
```

Comment: Just tested your codepen in Chrome, Firefox and Edge. The vertical scrollbar is working fine.

Comment: Works for me too ...and in IE11

Comment: wow, works for me (original poster) as well. hmm. Thanks